# Getting File Path error while adding file to files list in Customization Manager

Tags: acumatica

I am getting the file path or file name too long error (see screenshot below) while adding a file to the files list in customization manager. This happened after I upgrade it to 2018 R1. Before that it was working as normal till 2017 R2 but not after upgrading the site to 2018 R1. I tried to search in event log or trace, but did not find anything specific to error.

This is even happening when I create a new project, create a new VS project, compile in VS and then click on add file button in customization manager. If I do not bind it to VS then I am able to click on the add button and it works perfectly ok.

BTW, I am using VS 2015.

Not sure what is wrong. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the absolute path to your file, including the name of the file?

Comment: Ruslan, the issue is it does not give any info. I am getting above error dialog as soon as I click on (+) sign under Files in Customization Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krunal, the error message is for the most part self-explanatory. Some files inside your website folder exceed the limits defined in Windows and therefore cause the error message to pop up. If you create local Acumatica websites under the **Program Files** folder, I would highly recommend to create a folder on the **C** drive and place all your new websites in this folder. Hope that moving your website to another location will completely resolve an issue with an exceeded path and/or file name size.

Because this error was thrown by the .Net runtime and is caused by restrictions defined in Windows, I highly doubt there is something that can be done inside Acumatica Customization Manager to prevent this error from happening in the future. To me, this is clearly a configuration issue, very specific to your development environment.

---

**UPDATE:**

I did some additional research on that subject and apparently VS 2015 comes with an old version of Node.js and NPM (Node Package Manager). Because the version of NPM shipped with VS 2015 does not create a flat store of packages, you get this enormously long folder structure inside Acumatica website's **node_modules** folder, which eventually results in the file path or file name too long error.

I believe, VS 2017 comes with a more recent version of Node.js and NPM, which do create a flat store of packages. This should explain why an issue with a 2018 R1 Acumatica website got automatically resolved after you switched to VS 2017 from VS 2015.

Following the suggestion from [this blog post](https://blog.josequinto.com/2016/05/04/how-to-configure-visual-studio-2015-integration-with-latest-version-of-node-js-and-npm/#Upgrade-NPM-in-Visual-Studio-2015), I was able to upgrade node.js and NPM to their latest version and set up VS 2015 to use the latest version of node.js and NPM instead of the old one it comes with. After deleting the **node_modules** folder from my Acumatica website and restarting Visual Studio, this issue seems to finally get resolved.

Comment: I have also upgraded my 2018 R1 project to VS2017 with .Net Framework 4.7.1 and the error is gone now. Thanks Ruslan.

Comment: If using VS2017 there are options you can turn off to avoid getting the node_modules folder found in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876984/how-can-i-disable-npm-package-restore-in-visual-studio-2015