# After opening website in VS2017 - Error Publishing Customization

Tags: visual-studio-2017, acumatica

I am relatively new to Acumatica.  I have been following the Development series of training videos and hit a hard stop on T300 video 4 after opening the website in Visual Studio and then trying to publish the changes in my customization project (after detecting/updating changed files).

Error:
The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider, CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located.

My environment is pretty simple:

- Acumatica ERP 2018R1
- Visual Studio Community Edition
- Windows 10 Pro build 1803

I found a number of posts suggesting that I install a nuget package, which may or may not have helped but did not fix the problem.  (Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform)

I stumbled across a reference to the node_modules folder (sorry, lost that post link) which prompted me to check my TST vs DEV instances, and I found it does not exist in my TST instance.  I also then noticed that the error I received during publishing happens after a series of lines about node_modules.

After a little more digging, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/43494775 which seems to have stopped the node_modules folder from being created and appears to have solved my problem publishing inside of Acumatica.

Other posts for visual studio claimed that the issue comes from the C++ compiler not being included in GAC in VS2017, but I completed the T100 and T200 courses on VS2017 without any issue.  The problem seems to be connected specifically to opening the Acumatica Website in VS2017.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue that can confirm disabling NPM restores won't cause me headaches down the road?  Or is there a better solution?  I don't recall anything in the setup guides telling me to make this change, and I haven't found any references that this was an issue before VS2017.

Comment: Hi Brian, there shouldn't be any reference to C or C++, our framework is built on C#. Did you choose the wrong project type ? I would suggest to start from scratch

Comment: I didn't create the project.  All I did was open the Acumatica ERP website for my DEV instance in VS2017.  The website was created by the Acumatica ERP installation process.  The error seems to be connected to Visual Studio automatically creating the node_modules folder when I open the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do recall running into this in older version of 2018R1.

These posts helped me solve the issue:

This post solved it for me:
[How can I disable NPM package restore in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876984/how-can-i-disable-npm-package-restore-in-visual-studio-2015)

Also with help from this post:
[Getting File Path error while adding file to files list in Customization Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645512/getting-file-path-error-while-adding-file-to-files-list-in-customization-manager/48653055#48653055)

if you still have the node_modules related folder just delete it and you should be good (from what I can remember).

If these don't work try the latest 2018R1 build. (or at least 2018R1 Update 1)

Comment: Thanks.  I did remove the folder and found that I can publish customizations again from inside Acumatica.  The build is 18.100.0062.

Comment: The issue should have been resolved in update 1 (18.101.0039) which is the version after yours. Current version is Update 7. Upgrading Acumatica should remove the need to have these special configured settings.

Comment: Upgrading my version to the latest resolved the issue completely.  Thank you!